# Plugin allennlp_models could not be loaded: No module named 'allennlp.modules.transformer.t5'

Tags: python, allennlp

Windows machine, Ubuntu partition, Anaconda 4.10.1, Python 3.6.13, AllenNLP 2.2.0

Trying to use AllenNLP as part of Document retrieval task, but allennlp_models won't load properly. Using the final code block in [this blog post](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-use-allennlps-pretrained-ner-model-in-2021-b60335904fc3) as an example, I get the following errorss:

```
Plugin allennlp_models could not be loaded: No module named 'allennlp.modules.transformer.t5'

...

allennlp.common.checks.ConfigurationError: crf_tagger is not a registered name for Model. You probably need to use the --include-package flag to load your custom code. Alternatively, you can specify your choices using fully-qualified paths, e.g. {"model": "my_module.models.MyModel"} in which case they will be automatically imported correctly.
```

Tried:

- pip, conda, git clone installs for allennlp and allennlp_models
- steps in blog post above
- --include-package is supposed to solve the Config error, but will this even work if _models isn't loaded properly? Doubtful.
- import allennlp-models.[specific-models]

Is this a problem in a particular release of allennlp that I can avoid? Loading consistently fails on the t5 transformer- can I just remove this and hope for the best?? Many thanks, etc etc

Comment: Hi @jajderian, can you install the latest version of allennlp and allennlp-models (2.6.0)? T5 is a later addition, and was not a part of 2.2.0.

Comment: Hi, yep I'm on allennlp 2.6.0:

allennlp --version

ERROR - allennlp.common.plugins - Plugin allennlp_models could not be loaded: No module named 'allennlp.nn.checkpoint'
allennlp 2.6.0

Comment: Hi @jajderian, `allennlp.nn.checkpoint` has not been released yet and is available only in the main branch. You can take a look at https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md to see the upcoming unreleased changes. We will be making another release soon.

Comment: Thanks, I think updating NLTK has fixed this, but good to know there's another release coming soon